# Dispatch multiple jobs per user and process it at once

Tags: laravel

is somehow possible to set up dispatching multiple jobs at once per user? Like if worker name is texts, is possible to set up for user to dispatch like 2-3 same jobs per once and process them at once?. Now it works like that user can dispatch just one job and its waiting for that one to be finished and then its executing another one. I have set up 50 workers at laravel forge. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel naturally jobs will be dispatched at once. Note if you are relying on the time jobs are executing, you are working against what jobs actually are. Jobs are a way to offload long running tasks, where when it is executed is not important. As an example if multiple users would queue multiple jobs, it would not be out of the ordinary it could take a long time before all jobs are done.

If you got multiple workers job will be executed almost immediately and at the same time. If you want to control that they are executed after each other, you can dispatch them as a [chain](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#job-chaining). But this will never be at the same time, as it is executed in a chain.

```
Bus::chain([
    new JobOne,
    new JobTwo,
    new JobThree,
])->dispatch();
```